# How do I insert Start and End date and times for Outlook Calendar API call

Tags: python, django, outlook, office365, outlook-restapi

I'm using Microsoft's sample Django app and trying to read calendar events from now back to 1 year ago. The API request is done using Python Request functions:

```
response = requests.get(url, headers = headers, params = parameters)
```

Header is standard API request related:

```
headers = { 'User-Agent' : 'python_events/1.0',
            'Authorization' : 'Bearer {0}'.format(token),
            'Accept' : 'application/json',
            'X-AnchorMailbox' : user_email }
```

And, for parameters I'm passing:

```
  query_parameters = {'$top': '2500',
                      '$select': 'Id,Subject,Start,End',
                      '$orderby': 'Start/DateTime ASC'}
```

Now, I tried to define start and end dates as:

```
  now = datetime.utcnow()
  one_year = now - timedelta(days=365)
  now = now.isoformat()
  one_year = one_year.isoformat()
```

Then, tried to insert startDateTime and endDateTime parameters in the same query_parameters dict:

```
  query_parameters = {'$top': '2500',
                      '$select': 'Id,Subject,Start,End',
                      '$orderby': 'Start/DateTime ASC',
                      'startDateTime' : one_year,
                      'endDateTime': now
                     }
```

I'm still getting event dumps from before a year ago. What am I doing wrong here? Is query_parameters the right place to insert start and end date and times?

Comment: What is the value of `url`?

Comment: Hi Jason, the url value is: https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Me/Events

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the `startDateTime` and `endDateTime` parameters to limit the date range, you need to do a `GET` on  the `/calendarview` endpoint, not `/events`. The `/events` endpoint doesn't support those parameters.

Change your `url` to `https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Me/calendarview` and see if you get better results.

Comment: That was it! Thanks Jason, appreciate your help.